# How to scale custom made analytics engine?

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, elasticsearch, logstash, bigdata

We have a mid size analytics engine built on top of Elastic Search cluster.

We store send data to our servers in form of json, very similar to what Google Analytics might be doing. We push this entire data in ES cluster. As of now which amounts to ~60GB per day(Approx 2TB per month).

We have a data retention policy of few months lets say 6 months(As per pricing plan).

We provide dynamic reports like ....

1. all the users who are coming from United States and are using the chrome browser and are using the browser on an iPhone.
2. the sum of clicks on a particular button of all the users who are coming from referrer matching regex “http://www.google.com” and are based out of India and are using Desktop.

**PROBLEM**

It has worked for us pretty good till now, but we are facing a problem to scale. As we have already deployed 100s of servers to handle this amount of data & show near real time analytics.

What I am looking for here is that how can I optimise data storage and still show near real time slicing and dicing of data. Imagine how google analytics or mix panel might be storing and showing data in real time.

I am open any technology shift. Suggestions please. (Something similar to GA or Mix Panel is what we have in term of feature)

Do you guys thing storing this huge amount of data in some NO-SQL like mongodb will work and running MAP-Reduce on that data? But that might not be real time(We can expect a delay of 5-10 mins in showing data)

**Tech Stack Used(As of now)**

1. Apache/Nginx as webserver + application code
2. Programming Language(Ruby/PHP etc)
3. Log collection/parsing via logstash
4. Elasticsearch cluster to store and query data
5. SDK written in Javascript which pushes events to our server(Like GA)

We store event payload which looks something like this.

```
{
    "query_params":[

    ],
    "device_type":"Desktop",
    "browser_string":"Chrome 47.0.2526",
    "ip":"62.82.34.0",
    "screen_colors":"24",
    "os":"Mac OS X",
    "browser_version":"47.0.2526",
    "session":1,
    "country_code":"ES",
    "document_encoding":"UTF-8",
    "city":"Palma De Mallorca",
    "tz":"Europe/Madrid",
    "uuid":"A37F2D3A4B99FF003132D662EFEEAFCA",
    "combination_goals_facet_term":"c2_g1",
    "ts":1452015428,
    "hour_of_day":17,
    "os_version":"10.11.2",
    "experiment":465,
    "user_time":"2016-01-05T17:37:10.675000",
    "direct_traffic":false,
    "combination":"2",
    "search_traffic":false,
    "returning_visitor":false,
    "hit_time":"2016-01-05T17:37:08",
    "user_language":"es",
    "device":"Other",
    "active_goals":[
        1
    ],
    "account":196,
    "url":"http://someurl.com",
    "action":"click",
    "country":"Spain",
    "region":"Islas Baleares",
    "day_of_week":"Tuesday",
    "converted_goals":[

    ],
    "social_traffic":false,
    "converted_goals_info":[

    ],
    "referrer":"http://www.google.com",
    "browser":"Chrome",
    "ua":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36",
    "email_traffic":false
}
```

***EDIT***

"optimize data storage" means for every event we receive 70% data same in the json payload. However we keep on creating the new document in ES for event. I was hoping if somehow we stop storing the repeated keys of json and store only what changed in subsequent event payload. Thus optimizing storage space.

We are using SSDs on all our servers. What I am worried about is that what happens we talk about the scale of GA and similar amount of data. I doubt above mentioned Architecture or Tech will survive. Looking for suggestions for that sorta scale.

Comment: Your problem statement is very vague. "optimize data storage" doesn't mean much. If you can provide some concrete actual metrics and what you'd expect instead, it'd be a good start. Also we have no idea of your hardware specs. Help us help you!

Comment: @Val edited the post. However here I am not much worried about the Hardware in general. I am not sure the ES Cluster can survive data which may become as huge as Google Analytics(i know thats too much to ask) and still display near real time analytics.

Comment: Yandex (the makers of Yandex Metrics, Russia's google analytics) use their own DB, Clickhouse. And they recently [released it to public](https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse). It does just that (near-realtime slicing and dicing of events), and does it well. AND it uses regular SQL for queries, not some convoluted json-based object query protocol. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are already using the best-suited stack for such kind of use case. What I would suggest to work on fine tuning the elasticsearch optimizations if already not done.

Some suggestions could be

1. Think of using SSD's instead of HDD for elastic search cluster.
2. Think of using fine tuning parameters like "refresh_intervals"
3. Using auto scaling via cloud some load balancers in order to handle proper requests.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I'll check refresh_intervals again. However I am concerned about if ES cluster can deal with data as huge as GA might be storing for near real time analytics.